# Compiling c/cpp files in a directory given as an input

Tags: shell-script, directory, compiling

I need to write a script called **DirCompile** that receives a directory path as a command line argument and compile all the c/cpp files.

for example `helloWorld.c` file will  be compiled into `helloWorld.exe`.

all of the compiled files will be placed in a folder named `compiled files` under the current library, and it should also have the right permissions.

I more or less know the commands to what is required but I am failing to put it together

Comment: What commands have you tried to put together?

Comment: looks like a job for `make`.

Answer (score 0):

Something like the below might work.

```
#! /bin/sh
mkdir  -p  'compiled files'
for  x  in "$1"/*.c;    do  gcc  $x  -o "compiled files/${x%.c}.exe";    done
for  x  in "$1"/*.cpp;  do  g++  $x  -o "compiled files/${x%.cpp}.exe";  done
```

Comment: Why would you compile C source code files using `g++`?

Comment: @Kusalananda.  Good point.  Originally, I used `gcc`, but then I noticed that the questioner specified `c/cpp` files.  I will update my answer.  (`g++` can compile some C programs, but certainly not all of them.)

Comment: Note that your `$x` will contain a directory path, so e.g. `${x%.c}.exe` will too.

Comment: I believe my `$x` will only contain a directory if the directory name ends in `.c`.  I consider this behavior acceptable.  In any case, I read Ahmad's question as asking for general guidance, not a bulletproof solution.  And even if there is a directory that matches `*.c`, it will just print an error message, not abort.  A more likely concern, imo, would be if one of `*.c` (or `*.cpp`) did not match any files.

Answer (score 0):

Using a shell loop, calling a C compiler explicitly:

```
#!/bin/sh

mkdir -p "compiled files"

for src in "$1"/*.c "$1"/*.cpp; do
    case $src in
        *.c)   compiler=${CC:-cc}   ;;
        *.cpp) compiler=${CXX:-c++} ;;
    esac
    command "$compiler" -o "compiled files"/"$( basename "$src" "${src##*.}" )exe" "$src"
done
```

This will use the `$CC` and `$CXX` shell/environment variables as the compiler unless it's unset or empty, in which case it will default to using `cc` or `c++` depending on the suffix of the source file.

Using a shell loop, using `make` with implicit rules:

```
#!/bin/sh

mkdir -p "compiled files"

for src in "$1"/*.c "$1"/*.cpp; do
    make "${src%.*}" && mv "${src%.*}" "compiled files"/"$( basename "$src" "${src##*.}" )exe"
done
```

This will use implicit rules for building the executable (these are affected by environment variables like `$CC`, `$CXX`, `$CFLAGS` etc.)
Upon a successful build, the executable is renamed to fit your particular requirement to have an `.exe` filename suffix on the file.